# Get the object of an FCurve

Tags: python, transforms, graph-editor, fcurves, actions

I am getting the Graph Editor's visible FCurves using the following code:

```py
visible = context.visible_fcurves[:]
for fcurve in visible:
    #object code here
```

How do I get the object from this FCurve? In this example, Cube:
[image: Channels]

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marty has beat me to it, but the way I found is:

```py
found = [o for o in D.objects if o.animation_data and o.animation_data.action is fcurve.id_data]
```

where `fcurve` is the iterator variable in your loop, and `found` is a list of all objects sharing the animation data using this fcurve. Assuming there's exactly one, you could instead do:

```py
found = next(o for o in D.objects if o.animation_data and o.animation_data.action is fcurve.id_data)
```

And if the length of the oneliner is bothering you, walrus helps a bit:

```py
found = next(o for o in D.objects if (d:=o.animation_data) and d.action is fcurve.id_data)
```

Comment: I like this, as I didn't think to use the id_data to avoid looking through fcurves, but I have seen cases where o has animation_data but for corner case reasons there is no action. (For those playing along at home, `D` is set in the Python console, but not scripts.  It's equal to `bpy.data` in my script above.

Comment: @MartyFouts then it will compare `None` and `fcurve.id_data` identities and omit the object from the results.

Comment: Doh.  I knew that.  (Apparently not ;)

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know how to do this is to search objects to see if the fcurves are present:

```py
for object in bpy.data.objects:
    if object.animation_data and object.animation_data.action and object.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        for fcurve in object.animation_data.action.fcurves:
            if fcurve in visible:
                print(f"{object.name}")
```

- You can replace the `for...` with other ways of going through objects.  You might be able to use `context.active_object` or limit the search to only selected objects, et cetera.
- The first clause of the if statement separates objects that have animation data from those that don't.
- Even if an object has animation data the second clause is for obscure cases when the animation data doesn't have any actions.
- The third clause in the if statement is probably overkill, but I can't find anything that guarantees that if an object has an `action` that action will have `fcurves`.

This will only work for animation data directly associated with objects; which appears to be what you want.